# Android safe method of loading OpenGL textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

I've been working on my first game for Android, and I have a problem.
A bunch of users reported ANR on their phones on the stage of loading textures.
I have a bunch of jpg compressed textures, and it takes about 2 secs on my phone to unpack
and load them in opengl, and on emulator it takes half a minute to do it, and I don't get ANR in neither case, nevertheless I keep getting ANR reports.

I understand it's a heavy operation and it can take a lot of time to do (> 5 secs).
So I need to know a proper way to do all that lengthy loading (that wouldn't cause ANR on any device).

I used two methods that helps effectively avoid ANR  on emulator (I use it to model a slow device), but neither of them works for user:

1) Do all the loading in onSurfaceCreated(...) method.
2) Split loading into many small parts, and do one-by one in 
OnDrawFrame(...) method.

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Spin up a secondary thread to decompress the image(s).  Make sure to upload them on your main thread.